# Exception : 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle..... in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4, xcode9

This is my View Controller, in which I have set my collectionView and with its methods.

```
class HomeScreenViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var collectionViewOne: UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
     collectionViewOne.register(UINib(nibName: "recomendedcell1", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell1")
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("recommendedcell1", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! CustomCellOneCollectionViewCell
    return cell
}
```

this is my custom cell file

```
class CustomCellOneCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}
```

}

I have also used code below, for cell declaration.

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell1", for: indexPath) as! CustomCellOneCollectionViewCell
```

I have checked all connections, double-checked identifiers' names.
my view controller is a part of tab-bar controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While registert nib, nibName shoudbe Cell namee means CustomCellOneCollectionViewCell

```
collectionViewOne.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomCellOneCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell1")
collectionViewOne.delegate = self
collectionViewOne.datasource = self
```

and in cellForItemAt

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell1", for: indexPath) as! CustomCellOneCollectionViewCell
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your cell  `recommendedcell1`   Make sure that its SuperClass is type of  `CustomCellOneCollectionViewCell`

[image]

Why this line

```
let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("recommendedcell1", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! CustomCellOneCollectionViewCell
```

just `dequeueReusableCell`

```
          let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell1", for: indexPath) as! CustomCellOneCollectionViewCell
```

So your cell will be

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
   let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell1", for: indexPath) as! CustomCellOneCollectionViewCell
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Because I was getting the same exception with that one too. Thanks I will edit my question.

Comment: still ain't working, I have made sure its superclass is the same you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell : MyCustomView = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("your_reusable_identifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCellOneCollectionViewCell

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove this line

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("recommendedcell1", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! CustomCellOneCollectionViewCell
        return cell
}
```

try this one

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell  = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "recommendedcell1", for: indexPath) as!  CustomCellOneCollectionViewCell
        return cell

}
```

Comment: getting the same exception!

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was about **File Target**.

Make sure your xib file added to all targets.

[image]